# Which would be the best way to consume a web service using MVC in Android?

Tags: android, model-view-controller, android-volley

I'm currently working on a Android project, using MVC as architectural pattern. 
My app is a web service consumer, and so far, I'm using StringRequest to retrieve JSON in the controller.

Considering the pattern, where would be the best way to retrieve the response?

Comment: I'm not sure if you are asking for an workflow design or specific APIs/library to use? Simplest way is to request your data as string and then parse it to your model using gson. A  more complex way would be to use framework setup template that does the response parsing internally.

Comment: I'm asking about the design of the architecture, how to organize it better (sorry for the misunderstangding).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an async task or a loader or a generic background thread to invoke REST service.

Independently from where do you choose to invoke REST service, i suggest you to use [retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) to manage JSON result. With Retrofit you can manage response asynchronously.